# Mongoose can't save embedded documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mean-stack

I am trying to create a document in Mongo DB which has an embedded document within it. The model/schema for the document is as follows:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Cupboard Collection Schema
 var ShelfSchema = new Schema({
 shelf_name: {
    type: String
 },
 shelf_desc: {
    type: String
 }
});

var CupboardSchema = new Schema({
 cupboard_name: {
  type: String,
  required: true,
  unique: true
 },
cupboard_desc: {
 type: String,
 required: true
},
shelf: [ShelfSchema]
},
{
  timestamps: true
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Cupboard', CupboardSchema);
```

Image shows the code for saving the document.
[image: Code for saving document]

When i print the "newCupboard" in console, I am getting the document in exact format as follows:

```
{
_id: 58e4b972931dc809f4127b0b
cupboard_name: Cupboard A,
cupboard_desc: Cupboard A Details,
shelf: [ {
 shelf_name: Cupboard A,
 shelf_desc: Cupboard A Details,
 _id: 58e4c2742bfc0111dc47f149
 }]
}
```

But after the execution, the embedded document is not getting saved & no error is shown. Final result is as shown below:

```
{
 _id: 58e4b972931dc809f4127b0b
 cupboard_name: Cupboard A,
 cupboard_desc: Cupboard A Details
}
```

Can anybody help me to figure this out, why the embedded doc is not getting saved in mongo db ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't save the embedded document as the whole document inside another document. You'll have to save the '_id' of the document and at the time of fetching the record, you'll call `populate()` on the query.
So, let us suppose you have to save document in Cupboard schema, the schema will look like this -

```
var CupboardSchema = new Schema({
 cupboard_name: {
  type: String,
  required: true,
  unique: true
 },
cupboard_desc: {
 type: String,
 required: true
},
shelf: {
type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
ref: 'ShelfSchema'}
},
{
  timestamps: true
});
```

Now, at 'shelf' save the corresponding document, that you want to populate. And when you will be fetching the document, call `populate()` like -

```
CupboardSchemaModel.find({_id: <some-id-you-want-to-fetch>}).populate('shelf');
```

Comment: Isn't possible to directly create a document as per the model shown without separating them into two ? What is the advantage of doing it like what you said ? ( I am beginner with Mongo DB )